# Android fragment intent button next activity

Tags: android-intent

i have force close and i register SecondActivity in manifest

public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,false);
    Button mButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent mIntent=new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(mIntent);
}
    });
    return view;   
}
}
```

logCat

11-21 17:25:03.277: D/AndroidRuntime(382): Shutting down VM
11-21 17:25:03.277: W/dalvikvm(382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.star/com.example.star.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.star.MainActivity
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.star.MainActivity
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
11-21 17:25:03.297: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  ... 11 more

Comment: Please add your Log cat here so we can get better idea about what is the problem.

Comment: there's a ClassCastException happening in the MainActivity: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.star.MainActivity 11-21

Comment: im beginer what i can for fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice this:   *public class MainActivity extends **Fragment***

it's a fragment, not an activity. So if you handle it as an activity, it will fail badly, for instamce, as it is a fragment, you should not declare it in the AndroidManifest.xml. Change it to an Activity, or make new Activity that has this fragment in it.

Comment: how can i create button in Fragment to activity?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejoyamnuibz5nmf/Star.rar?dl=0           this is my project can you fix?

Answer (score -1):

The exception clearly says it can't find the class `com.example.new2.MainActivity`.

Seems like you have changed the name of your activity class from `MainActivity` to `Activitymain` but not updated the same in `Manifest.xml` file.

Comment: im create new activity and fix but again force close

Comment: It's not that it "can't find", there's a ClassCastException happening in the MainActivity: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.star.MainActivity 11-21